# Add new column to matrix by doing operation between rows

Tags: r

i have this matrix here named Sorted.

```
     [,1]     [,2]       [,3]       [,4]      
[1,] "a"     "14.06863" "11.50424" "333173.1"
[2,] "b"     "14.50265" "11.89501" "387709.7"
[3,] "c"     "14.55234" "11.95746" "402124"  
[4,] "d"     "14.78606" "12.14149" "453059.3"
[5,] "e"     "15.1697"  "12.51004" "496142.1"
[6,] "f"     "14.41104" "11.81296" "539661.3"
[7,] "g"     "14.86976" "12.23968" "603475.4"
```

What i need is to add another column, a 5th column which takes the values from subtracting each value of the column 4 with the previous one. It would be like this:

```
     [,1]     [,2]       [,3]       [,4]        [,5]     
[1,] "a"     "12.06863" "8.50424" "433173.1"   "433173.1 - 0"
[2,] "b"     "12.50265" "8.89501" "487709.7"   "487709.7 - 433173.1 "
[3,] "c"     "12.55234" "8.95746" "502124"     "502124 - 487709.7"
[4,] "d"     "12.78606" "8.14149" "553059.3"   "553059.3 - 502124 "
[5,] "e"     "14.1697"  "8.51004" "596142.1"   "596142.1 - 553059.3"
[6,] "f"     "11.41104" "8.81296" "639661.3"   "639661.3 - 596142.1 "
[7,] "g"     "15.86976" "8.23968" "703475.4"   "703475.4 - 639661.3"
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `matrix` can only store one type (e.g. character, numeric) of data. Since you have letters in column 1, the entire matrix is coerced to character, and so you can no longer perform arithmetic operations on the data.

A `data.frame`, on the other hand, only requires that each *column* contains data of a consistent type, whereas different columns can contain different types of data.

Starting with your matrix, `Sorted`, try the following:

```
# Convert the matrix to a data.frame
d <- as.data.frame(Sorted, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
# Convert all columns except the first to numeric
d[, -1] <- apply(d[, -1], 2, as.numeric)
# Create a new column called diff, which is column 4 minus column 3
d$diff <- d[, 4] - d[, 3]

d

  V1       V2       V3       V4     diff
1  a 14.06863 11.50424 333173.1 333161.6
2  b 14.50265 11.89501 387709.7 387697.8
3  c 14.55234 11.95746 402124.0 402112.0
4  d 14.78606 12.14149 453059.3 453047.2
5  e 15.16970 12.51004 496142.1 496129.6
6  f 14.41104 11.81296 539661.3 539649.5
7  g 14.86976 12.23968 603475.4 603463.2
```

---

**Edit:**

As pointed out in the comments, `diff` should contain the difference between values in column 4 and their values in previous rows.

A simple way to achieve this is:

```
d$diff <- c(d[1, 4], diff(d[, 4]))

d
  V1       V2       V3       V4     diff
1  a 14.06863 11.50424 333173.1 333173.1
2  b 14.50265 11.89501 387709.7  54536.6
3  c 14.55234 11.95746 402124.0  14414.3
4  d 14.78606 12.14149 453059.3  50935.3
5  e 15.16970 12.51004 496142.1  43082.8
6  f 14.41104 11.81296 539661.3  43519.2
7  g 14.86976 12.23968 603475.4  63814.1
```

Comment: User asked to subtract values in 4th column, not to subtract column 3 from column 4

Comment: I realise now that the OP requires the new column to contain the col 4 - a lagged copy of col 4.

Comment: This was really useful, but what i need is not d[, 4] - d[, 3] rather than operations between the numbers in the 4th column. I need to subtract and find if there is any difference at all between the second row column 4 subtracted to first row column 1 and so on, would be in your example, [1,V4] has no row before it so the difference should be 0, then [2,V4] - [1,V4], then [3,V4]-[2,V4]and so on...

Comment: Yes thanks, it was great, just one last thing, how can i modify it, so when the first row subtracts the difference to be 0, because it doesn't have a previous row

Comment: `c(d[1, 4], diff(d[, 4]))` says to leave the first element of column 4 unmodified. I've added the final output for clarification.

Comment: Ah, okay, how do i always put 0 for the first element of the column?

Comment: In your question, you show that you expect the first value in column 5 to be `433173.1 - 0`, which is not zero. If you want it to be zero, then do `c(0, diff(d[, 4]))` instead.

Answer (score 1):

First create sample matrix

```
M <- cbind(letters[1:10], matrix(rnorm(30), ncol=3))
```

Generate values in new column using `sapply`

```
newcol <- c(M[1,4], 
    sapply(2:10, FUN=function(x) {
        # subtract value at x-1 from value at x
        as.numeric(M[as.numeric(x),4])-as.numeric(M[as.numeric(x)-1,4])} ) )
```

Bind to original matrix

```
M <- cbind(M, newcol)
```

Comment: Please confirm that your code runs without error - each code block triggers errors for me.

Answer (score 0):

If matrix name is M then this should do the trick - will create a column diff and set its value from diff of column V4.

M$diff <- M$4
M$diff[2:length(M$V4)] <- diff(M$V4, 1)